# Electron Leaves 1px Border Around titleBarOverlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I'm very new to Electron and Node.js so forgive any misuse of the terminology.

I'm working on a Windows 10 application.  I'm trying to gain the ability to customize the title bar area of my app (along the lines of other Electron apps like Github Desktop or Discord).

From what I found by searching and reading, there are two ways to do this:  Do a frameless window and create all the elements yourself including the window control buttons OR do a frameless window and use the [Window Controls Overlay](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization) (`titleBarOverlay`).  I would prefer to do the latter just because it's less code and the few parameters `titleBarOverlay` has is enough to get the buttons to look the way I want.

The problem is that the overlay leaves a 1px gap around the buttons and I can't find a way to adjust the position of the overlay.  This is what the window buttons look like (red title bar for contrast:

[image]

This is the window creation code in `main.js`:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1100,
        height: 900,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
        },
        backgroundColor: "#0a0a0a",
        frame: false,
        titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
        titleBarOverlay: {
            color: '#323232',
            symbolColor: '#ffffff',
            height: 30
        }
    })

    win.loadFile("index.html");
}
```

The style in `index.html` includes this (`title_bar` is just a div directly under the `body` element):

```css
body {
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#title_bar {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of this gap?  If not, is the preferred method of accomplishing the look I want to add in the window buttons manually as mentioned above?

I have not been able to find much documentation on `titleBarOverlay`.  Is this a very new feature?  Or a feature that is being phased out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a standard thing for all windows.

To test this, drag any (windowed) application installed on your computer over a white background. The result will be the same, being a `1px` border around the whole window.

To achieve your desired look, you will need to drop the `titleBarStyle` and `titleBarOverlay` options and "build" the title bar yourself.

Below are two SO Answers I have provided in the past that may get you started in building your own title bar.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75840891/2627338
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72158666/2627338

In answer to your questions, `titleBarOverlay` has been around for a while now and as far as I know, there are no plans to phase it out.

For additional reading see:

- [Electron - Window Controls Overlay](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#window-controls-overlay-macos-windows)
- [Web Incubator Community Group - Window Controls Overlay for Installed Desktop Web Apps](https://github.com/WICG/window-controls-overlay/blob/main/explainer.md)